# How to fix 'setAttributeNode(att)' to add attribute vice modify existing?

Tags: javascript, r, dom, shiny

I am using the `shinyJS` package as well as `shiny` tags and traditional HTML to add the attribute 'title' to existing elements. I am able to do this without issue within the console (inspector [Google CHROME]) but when attempting to apply the same inputs via either ui.R or server.R, either nothing changes or the actual text value changes vice adding title (tooltip).

As mentioned above, I have tried the following:
`shinyJS`: html()
`shiny`: tags$HTML; tags$body(tags$script())
HTML: Adding the change in HTML file (mychange.html) and sourcing from www

The input to modify (add tooltip)

```
pickerInput(
inputid = "ReqTabSel6",
label = '',
choices = c('Choice 1', 'Choice 2', 'Choice 3'),
mulitple = F,
options = list(
style = "btn-info"))
```

Here is the correct function (as it updates when running in console under web inspector):

```
var addToolTip1 = document.querySelector('#form>div:nth-child(10)>div>div>div>ul>li.selected>a') 
var att = document.createAttribute("title");      
att.value = "I am a tooltip title";                          
addToolTip1 .setAttributeNode(att);
```

However, in R...

## shinyJS

```
server.R
...
observeEvent(input$ReqTabSel6, {
shinyJS::html(id = NULL, 
html = "var addToolTip1 = document.querySelector('#form>div:nth-child(10)>div>div>div>ul>li.selected>a') 
var att = document.createAttribute("title");      
att.value = "I am a tooltip title";                          
addToolTip1 .setAttributeNode(att);",
selector = '#form>div:nth-child(10)>div>div>div>ul>li.selected>a')
})

##This updates the actual 'choice' value from 'Choice 1' to 'Choice1I am a tooltip title')

#Changing html to read:
html = 'title = "I am a tooltip title"',

#This replaces the choice (e.g. Choice 1) value so the drop down now has:

I am a tooltip title
Choice 2 
Choice 3
```

Would like to create the tooltip for each child (tab index) of the pickerInput choices. Should just add 'title' attribute to other attributes within the designated node.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! Answering it myself in case another user runs in to this.

```
#server.R
observeEvent(input$actionbutton1,{
shinyjs::html(
html='<a tabindex="0" class=""...title="Your tooltip here"...></a>',
add=FALSE,
selector = '#form>div>form>div>div:nth-child(5)>div>div>div>ul>li:nth-child(4)' #This is the jquerySelector. Note that it will be different for each unique application. You will need to change the 'nth-child(#)' to the specific choice within 'SelectInput' to get a tooltip specific to that choice.)
})
```